# I want to know about column in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 10 images files and I'd like to align them with the Bootstrap grid system. How can I write HTML which will show 4 images on desktop and 2 images on mobile?

```html
<div class="container">
 <h2><a id="gallery">head</a></h2>
 
 <div class="box">
    <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img src="..."></div>
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img src="..."></div>   
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img src="..."></div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img src="..."></div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img src="..."></div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img src="..."></div>
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img src="..."></div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img src="..."></div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img src="..."></div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img src="..."></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Is this right?

Comment: In the official documentation check **Grid options**: see how aspects of the Bootstrap grid system work across multiple devices with a handy table http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 0):

First you need to link bootstrap.css to your project.

Every project that uses bootstrap should start with following lines:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
```

Next should go link to bootstrap:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Look at snippet:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
 <h2><a id="gallery">head</a></h2>
 
 <div class="box">
    <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img src="..."></div>
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img src="..."></div>   
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img src="..."></div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img src="..."></div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img src="..."></div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img src="..."></div>
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img src="..."></div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img src="..."></div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img src="..."></div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img src="..."></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

#### And what is `box`?